# create instance with big volume and found retry filter running in nova-scheduler.log then fail with

Tags: iscsi

Need some help,
about RetryFilter running then create instance show 2 ip addresses .

I have situation about ,
1.Create volume with big size about more than 80GB
2.Run "launch as instance" then it take around more than 1 minute in
nova-scheduler.log show as below log

Log

2018-02-05 15:58:45.568 170177 WARNING os_brick.initiator.connectors.iscsi [req-90edde34-d40c-4afa-96bf-b726bc408ef6 20f09a8909564dcba477e5be52ea9f63 ac8f54f0a2e0482aa884773510fdba64 - - -] Failed to connect to iSCSI portal 10.x.xy.217:3260.
2018-02-05 15:58:45.569 170177 ERROR os_brick.initiator.connectors.iscsi [req-90edde34-d40c-4afa-96bf-b726bc408ef6 20f09a8909564dcba477e5be52ea9f63 ac8f54f0a2e0482aa884773510fdba64 - - -] Could not login to any iSCSI portal.

#### Log

As googling , found about scheduler_default_filters = RetryFilter
try to running then the process for create instance re-run again , so it will show 2 ip address receive during create instance , then a while it will error
Could not login to any iSCSI portal

#### Running on 1 controller+compute+block storage , 3 compute+block storage

In case of create lower volume size and instance not have any problem.
Please kindly recommend
Thank you : )

I try to found a way to disable RetryFilter in nova.conf but could not see.

Answer (score 0):

I try to edit scheduler_driver_task_period
default set for scheduler_driver_task_period=60 sec
after that re-run build instance process again so it will show and acquire 2 ip addresses after that will show fail on created process.

## vi /etc/nova/nova.conf

[scheduler]
scheduler_driver_task_period = 100

## service nova-* restart

: )